# YUI3 (JS) setStyle using vendor prefixes 

Tags: css, yui3

How do I use YUI3's set style to set something like `-webkit-border-radius: 10px;`?

example:

```
Y.one('#mydiv').setStyle('-webkit-border-radius', '10');
```

Comment: Are you saying that your example doesn't work?

Comment: It's not working for me ... does it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work.

I think you are missing the 'px' for

```
Y.one('#mydiv').setStyle('-webkit-border-radius', '10');
```

Should be

```
Y.one('#mydiv').setStyle('-webkit-border-radius', '10px');
```

Comment: Your example works, but I can't get `Y.one('#mydiv').setStyle('-moz-border-radius', '10px');` to work in FF?  Any ideas?

Comment: Gotta say as far as the -moz/FF border-radius I'm stumped as well. The only think I can thing of is YUI preemptively took away support for -moz-border-radius based on plans for FF to move to border-radius (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/-moz-border-radius) Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Somehow setStyle doesn't work if we need to set style something like "COLOR : RED !IMPORTANT;" any suggestions?

Comment: See webinista's answer below - that's why -moz-border-radius doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Use camel case. When DOM scripting, [style properties](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#the-cssstyledeclaration-interface) should always be set using camelCase. Webkit is lax about that and violates spec.

```
Y.one('#mydiv').getDOMNode().style.setProperty('mozBorderRadius', '10');
```

For `border-radius`, it's pretty safe (these days) to skip the vendor prefix, though.

[Source](https://miketaylr.com/posts/2014/01/yui-set-style-differences.html)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else still needs to accomplish this, here's how I did it:

```
Y.one('#mydiv').getDOMNode().style.setProperty('-moz-border-radius', '10');
```